# What's the difference between @ and * with python matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy

I know one does one kind of matrix multiplication and the other does another kind but can never remember the difference.

Doing

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix([[1, 2],[3,4]])

>>> print(a * a)
[[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]

>>> print(a @ a)
[[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]
```

appears to give the same answer which confuses me.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: No built-in type supports `@`, IIRC. This should be documented in types that *do* support `@`, such as those provided by the `numpy` module.

Comment: `@` is equivalent of matrix mutiplication, at least for higher dimensions. And `*` is cellwise multiplication.

Comment: Except for np.matrix (as opposed to np.array); np.matrix maps * to matrix multiplication as it is a special class that predates @ and was used to make it do 'natural' matrix multiplication.  This is presumably one of the reasons it is considered deprecated.

Comment: @theEpsilon numpy.matrix is deprecated.  You can use numpy.array with @ instead.

Comment: @YoanaG the question has been reopened. Feel free to submit an answer

Comment: @Max the question has been reopened. Feel free to submit an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a * b` is a multiplication operator - it will return elements in `a` multiplied by elements in `b`.

When `a` and `b` are both matrices (specifically defined by `np.matrix`) the result will be the same as the `@` operator.

`a @ b` is matrix multiplication (dot product when used with vectors). If you haven't specified that `a` is a matrix and have used an array instead `a * a` would return every element in `a` squared.